# Android notification at specific date

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-date

I have to create an app in which I must set a date and at that specific date at 9 O'clock, I must give a notification. What is the simplest method of doing this? I want the app to work even when the app gets killed anyway. Is AlarmManager a solution?

Comment: i meant that i could still get that notification without accessing the app again

Comment: The OP obviously meant if he/she takes out the battery and replaces it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To schedule an Action you can use the AlarmManager

Try this code it's work for me:

1 / Declare the BroadcastReceiver CLASS to launch the Action, this class can be inside your activity or outside in an other java file

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("param"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

2/ Inside your Oncreate Method put this code

```
AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("ALARM_ACTION");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

    Intent intent = new Intent("ALARM_ACTION");
    intent.putExtra("param", "My scheduled action");
    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    // I choose 3s after the launch of my application
    alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+3000, operation) ;
```

Launch your App a Toast will be appeared after 3 seconds, So  you can change "System.currentTimeMillis()+3000" with your wake up time.

Answer (score 4):

You must use an `AlarmManager` to set an alarm of [`RTC_WAKEUP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP) type.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

> When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is
>   broadcast by the system, **automatically starting the target application**
>   if it is not already running. Registered alarms are retained while the
>   device is asleep (and can optionally **wake the device up** if they go off
>   during that time), **but will be cleared if it is turned off and
>   rebooted**.

So this means that:

- You don't need a continually running service to achieve this.
- To may need a `BroadcastListener` that listens to the BOOT_COMPLETE
  event to re-register the alarm after a device reboot.

Answer (score 3):

You should create the app as an [android service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.
>   Another application component can start a service and it will continue
>   to run in the background even if the user switches to another
>   application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service to
>   interact with it and even perform interprocess communication (IPC).
>   For example, a service might handle network transactions, play music,
>   perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the
>   background.

Answer (score 1):

Alarm manager is the solution i guess. you should set the alarm manager to a specific time and then make it call the notification in its onstart. and this should be implemented within a service. i hope it helped.